# How To Write To Txt File Using If Else Statement Within a Button

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to find a way to write information gathered via scenebuilder into a .txt file.  I managed to use if else statements to produce the desired results within the output window.  Sadly, I am unable to find a way to save the file.  I need a way to save and restore the information.  Please help.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package javafxapplication1;

import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;


/**
*
* @author cwcis
*/
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

private Label label;
@FXML
private Button save;
@FXML
private Button restore;
@FXML
private Button calculate;
@FXML
private TextField textcalccost;
@FXML 
private RadioButton vanilla;
@FXML 
private RadioButton chocolate;
@FXML 
private RadioButton strawberry;
@FXML
private CheckBox nuts;
@FXML
private CheckBox cherries;
@FXML 
private ToggleGroup IceCream;

@FXML
private void handleButtonSaving(ActionEvent event) {
if(vanilla.isSelected()) {
System.out.println("Vanilla");
}
if(chocolate.isSelected()) {
System.out.println("Chocolate");
}
if(strawberry.isSelected()) {
System.out.println("Strawberry");
}
if(nuts.isSelected()) {
System.out.println("With_Nuts");
}
else {
System.out.println("Without_Nuts");
}
if(cherries.isSelected()) {
System.out.println("With_Cherries");
}
else {
System.out.println("Without_Cherries");
}
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonRestore(ActionEvent event) {  
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonCalculateCost(ActionEvent event) {
double myTotal = 0.0;
    
myTotal += retrieveIceCreamCost();
myTotal += retrieveToppingsCost();
myTotal += retrieveTaxCost();
    
showAlert(myTotal);
}

private void showAlert(double theTotal) {
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Ice Cream Shop");
alert.setHeaderText("Order Confirmation");
alert.setContentText("Order: " + (retrieveIceCreamCost() + 
retrieveToppingsCost()) 
+ "\nTax: " + retrieveTaxCost() + "\nTotal: " + theTotal);
alert.showAndWait();
}

private double retrieveIceCreamCost() {
double iceCreamCost = 0.0;

if(vanilla.isSelected()) {
iceCreamCost = 2.25;
}
if(chocolate.isSelected()) {
iceCreamCost = 2.25;
}
if(strawberry.isSelected()) {
iceCreamCost = 2.25;
}
return iceCreamCost;
}

private double retrieveToppingsCost() {
double toppingsCost = 0.0;
    
if(cherries.isSelected()) {
toppingsCost += 0.50;
}
if(nuts.isSelected()) {
toppingsCost += 0.50;
}
return toppingsCost;
}    

private double retrieveTaxCost() {
double taxCost = 0.0;

if(cherries.isSelected()) {
taxCost += .03;
}
if(nuts.isSelected()) {
taxCost += .03;
}
if(vanilla.isSelected()) {
taxCost += .14;
}
if(chocolate.isSelected()) {
taxCost += .14;
}
if(strawberry.isSelected()) {
taxCost += .14;
}
return taxCost; 
}

public FXMLDocumentController() {
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
// TODO
}    

}
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want to save? `"Order: " + (retrieveIceCreamCost() + 
retrieveToppingsCost()) 
+ "\nTax: " + retrieveTaxCost() + "\nTotal: " + theTotal` ?

Comment: I am trying to save whatever the user checks in the popup box and restore that information later.  The information you highlighted is not the information I want to display. I only want to save the flavor of ice cream, and what toppings they do or do not have.

Answer (score 0):

To track iceCream selected, simply add new field `iceCream`. And assign a value to it once it's selected. Do the same with you `toppingsCost`:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private String iceCream;
    private double toppingsCost;

....
    private void handleButtonSaving(ActionEvent event) {
        if(vanilla.isSelected()) {
        iceCream = "Vanilla";
        System.out.println(iceCream);
        }
        if(chocolate.isSelected()) {
        iceCream = "Chocolate";
        System.out.println(iceCream);
        }
        ...

    private void handleButtonCalculateCost(ActionEvent event) {
        double myTotal = 0.0;

        myTotal += retrieveIceCreamCost();
        toppingsCost = retrieveToppingsCost();
        myTotal +=  toppingsCost;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider how `RadioButton`s are grouped by a `ToggleGroup`. In code:

```
final ToggleGroup icecream = new ToggleGroup();

RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Vanilla");
rb1.setToggleGroup(icecream);
rb1.setSelected(true);

RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Chocolate");
rb2.setToggleGroup(icecream);

RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton("Strawberry");
rb3.setToggleGroup(icecream);
```

You can handle all selection by the ToggleGroup component.

```
RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) icecream.getSelectedToggle();

ObservableList<Toggle> radioButtons = icecream.getToggles();
```

Writing the `selected` radio button's label (say "Vanilla") and later reading "Vanilla" and looping through all `radioButtons` to select the matching one is not too circumstantial.